# Container with shape like circle lines border and textblock

Tags: wpf

I am creating grid dynamically and adding 200 rows and 240 columns and adding stackpanel at each position of the grid So totally i am drawing 4800 stackpanels  .Now i want to add lines circle and 3 text blocks in each of the stackpanel 
Till I am adding grid add stackpanel it working fine and rendering all controls within 4 seconds which is okay .But as i started adding text block as a child control in scakpanel it taking too much time . Should I use any other better and light weight control . Or instead of adding text block can use DrawText on show text in stack panel. I further want to use drag drop functionality for stack panel so i must use only container will move along with its child elements

Comment: Greetings! Please have a look at the guidelines for asking a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Currently it is very hard to understand your problem and your intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can avoid adding the columns and the rows phase, instead of using a Grid you can simply use a canvas and handle the tabular view (rows and columns) from your code behind using the the Left and Top properties.

Beside, a canvas will be convenient to use the drag and drop functionnality. you can use for that the `MouseDragElementBehavior`. but then you have to deal with absolute positioning according to your Parent Window rather then the Top and Left Properites. It still realtively easy to do.

If you're   using a large view where there is only a part of it displayed, you can load only the part in view.

I Hope this will be helpfull.